# After using the scanning line filling algorithm, there is a gap at the edge of the contour (unfilled)

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, brush

On the Android platform, After filling the specified area with scan lines (currently only supports convex shapes), I found that there are a few unfilled gaps at the edges of the outline.

It looks like this:

[image: Fill renderings]

They are mainly concentrated in the upper right corner of the filled area, and there is a small amount of blank space in the upper left corner. The implementation code is as follows:

```kotlin
class Fill02 : MainActivity.IFill {
    private val pixel = ByteBuffer.allocate(3)
    // Color to be filled
    private val color = ByteArray(3)
    private var xScanLeft = 0
    private var xScanRight = 0

    override fun fill(x: Int, y: Int, minX: Int, maxX: Int, minY: Int, maxY: Int, callback: MainActivity.IFillCallback) {
        val surfaceWidth = maxX - minX
        val surfaceHeight = maxY - minY

        GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel)
        pixel.position(0)

        color[0] = pixel.get(0)
        color[1] = pixel.get(1)
        color[2] = pixel.get(2)

        var xLeft = x
        var xRight = x

        while (isSameColor(xLeft - 1, y) && 0 < xLeft) {
            xLeft--
        }

        while (isSameColor(xRight + 1, y) && xRight < surfaceWidth) {
            xRight++
        }

        callback.fullCallback(xLeft.toFloat(), surfaceHeight - y.toFloat())
        callback.fullCallback(xRight.toFloat(), surfaceHeight - y.toFloat())

        var yUp = y
        xScanLeft = xLeft
        xScanRight = xRight

        while (xScanLeft < xScanRight && yUp < maxY) {
            scanLine(++yUp, minX, maxX, surfaceHeight, callback)
        }

        var yDown = y
        xScanLeft = xLeft
        xScanRight = xRight

        while (xScanLeft < xScanRight && minY < yDown) {
            scanLine(--yDown, minX, maxX, surfaceHeight, callback)
        }
    }

    private fun scanLine(y: Int, minX: Int, maxX: Int, surfaceHeight: Int, callback: MainActivity.IFillCallback) {
        if (isSameColor(xScanLeft, y)) {
            while (minX < xScanLeft && isSameColor(xScanLeft - 1, y)) {
                xScanLeft--
            }
        } else {
            while (xScanLeft < xScanRight && !isSameColor(++xScanLeft, y)) {
            }
        }

        if (isSameColor(xScanRight, y)) {
            while (xScanRight < maxX && isSameColor(xScanRight + 1, y)) {
                xScanRight++
            }
        } else {
            while (xScanLeft < xScanRight && !isSameColor(--xScanRight, y)) {
            }
        }

        callback.fullCallback((xScanLeft).toFloat(), (surfaceHeight - y).toFloat())
        callback.fullCallback((xScanRight).toFloat(), (surfaceHeight - y).toFloat())
    }

    private fun isSameColor(x: Int, y: Int): Boolean {
        GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel)
        pixel.position(0)
        return (color[0] == pixel.get(0) &&
                color[1] == pixel.get(1) &&
                color[2] == pixel.get(2))
    }
}
```

The `callback.fullCallback` method code is as follows:

```kotlin
override fun fullCallback(x: Float, y: Float) {
    buffer.put((x - mSurfaceSize.x) / mSurfaceSize.x)
    buffer.put((mSurfaceSize.y - y) / mSurfaceSize.y)
}

override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {
    mSurfaceSize.set(width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f)
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
}
```

The vertex shader code is as follows:

```c
attribute vec2 vPosition;

uniform float vPointSize;

void main() {
    gl_PointSize = vPointSize;
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The complete source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/excing/AndroidOpenGLES20Demo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/me/excq/androidopengles20demo/toy02).

May I ask what is the problem?

Attachment 1:

After modifying the code, the picture has been exported.

[image]

The code for exporting pictures is as follows::

```kotlin
private fun save() {
    isSave = false
    val w = mSurfaceSize.x.toInt() * 2
    val h = mSurfaceSize.y.toInt() * 2
    val screenshotSize = w * h
    val pixels = IntBuffer.allocate(screenshotSize)
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(screenshotSize)
        for (i in 0 until h) {
            for (j in 0 until w) {
                buffer.put((h - i - 1) * w + j, pixels.get(i * w + j));
            }
        }
        val config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, config)
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255))
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
        val out = FileOutputStream(savePath)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it maybe that you have aliasing in the black line so that bright points are actually not white and so a different color than the inner background? The image you posted seems to have aliasing also on the filled color, so I have a doubt if it is really the output image or if the export/save process has altered it. For this reason I am not sure it is an aliasing problem but I still suspect it is. Can you share the actual original input image?

Comment: @DiegoMazzaro Yes, you are right, the picture was obtained through screenshots. After modifying the code, the picture has been exported and the picture has been attached to the original post.

Comment: I was asking an input image.. ..can you provide also that one? Or have you maybe already verified it has (has not) aliasing at that stage?